# How can I sync databases between two local virtual development environments

Tags: mysql, database, local, development-environment

i would ask you, what is best practices (or if it is even possible) to sync database between two computers. I have one computer at work and one at home. I have two identical virtual environments and I want when I finish my work on one computer to continue with on the other one. For app code I use git to share and it´s perfect, but I cannot find the satisfying solution for database. I´ve google and read a lot about it and so maybe it´s a wrong way at all. I´ve used remote database but there are speed limitation and internet connection need.
Many thanks for your opinions.

Comment: This is a good question, but one thing you should clarify - do you want a both direction synchronization?
This means you would need both DB's to be up and running simultaneously.

What the size of the DB you want to synchronize? is stopping the database and uploading the DB files to Git is not feasible?

I feel like replication is an overkill for app development environment.

Comment: And another question - is the DB global for the app (all app users use the same DB) or is it local for each instance / user of the app?

Comment: No, I don´t need the both direction synchronization. Only one computer is on in one moment. The size is small, eg. ~50 MB. Do you mean put dump under git version control?
Yes the DB is global, but there is only one user, me :-) It´s development DB.

Comment: No, each database has database files (which after stopping the DB you can copy to another machine and start it there), try to look at backup and recovery of DB's (you can treat any database shutdown as taking a backup, and every restart on another machine as a recovery).

If the DB is small, and can fit on Git, I think that's the simplest way to do it (though it might require a short script to do the "recovery")

look under physical full offline(raw) backup: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/backup-types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a statement based MySQL replication. You can't go wrong. 
-- Make sure you have a script that checks your server connections
-- Make sure you have a script that measures the lag, (just if the thread is stuck on a processing binlog) checks your slave I/O and SQL thread.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't sync database between development environment, you either have a migration system and a faker system to populate the database.

Example of a migration system:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Populate database; https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding